# Get All rows from virtual table when no query

Tags: android, sqlite, fts3

I need to know if it's possible to get all rows from fts table when user doesn't type any text.

I need this, because when app starts, I need to show all rows.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no MATCH expression that would return all records.

Just make a special case for the empty string, and use the plain

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Yes. Simple like this! Thanks!